# libpcap: select always returns fd count

Tags: c, linux, select, pcap, libpcap

I am using the `select(2)` function to watch for changes on file descriptor obtained by `pcap_get_selectable_fd`. When `select(2)` returns after what appears to be amount of time specified as a timeout, value equal to number of file descriptors in fdset is returned. Subsequent call to `pcap_next_ex` returns 0 (meaning no packets were available). I checked if some packets were dropped using `pcap_stats` but both 'drop' and 'ifdrop' counters were empty.

I also apply Berkeley Packet Filter on pcap resource handle, which according to documentation for `pcap_get_selectable_fd` caused some issues on BSD and Mac OS X. Could it be somehow related even that I am running Linux?

My test machine runs Linux kernel 3.13.3-1-ARCH and uses libpcap-1.6.2. On my development machine everything runs as I would expect (kernel 3.17.7-200.fc20.x86_64, libpcap-1.5.3).

#### Excerpt from packet capture initialization

```
for ( i = 0; i < etherpoke_conf->filter_cnt; i++ ){
    struct bpf_program bpf_prog;

    session_data_init (&(pcap_session[i]));

    pcap_session[i].handle = pcap_create (etherpoke_conf->filter[i].interface, pcap_errbuff);

    rval = pcap_set_promisc (pcap_session[i].handle, !etherpoke_conf->filter[i].rfmon);

    if ( etherpoke_conf->filter[i].rfmon ){
        rval = pcap_can_set_rfmon (pcap_session[i].handle);

        if ( rval == 1 ){
            rval = pcap_set_rfmon (pcap_session[i].handle, 1);
        } else {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s: cannot enable monitor mode on interface '%s': %s\n", argv[0], etherpoke_conf->filter[i].interface, pcap_geterr (pcap_session[i].handle));
            exitno = EXIT_FAILURE;
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    rval = pcap_set_timeout (pcap_session[i].handle, SELECT_TIMEOUT_MS);

    rval = pcap_setnonblock (pcap_session[i].handle, 1, pcap_errbuff);

    rval = pcap_activate (pcap_session[i].handle);

    rval = pcap_compile (pcap_session[i].handle, &bpf_prog, etherpoke_conf->filter[i].match, 0, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN);

    rval = pcap_setfilter (pcap_session[i].handle, &bpf_prog);

    pcap_freecode (&bpf_prog);

    pcap_session[i].fd = pcap_get_selectable_fd (pcap_session[i].handle);
}
```

#### Excerpt from the main loop

```
while ( main_loop ){
    time_t current_time;
    struct pcap_pkthdr *pkt_header;
    const u_char *pkt_data;
    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set fdset_read;
    int last_fd;

    FD_ZERO (&fdset_read);
    last_fd = 0;
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = SELECT_TIMEOUT_MS * 1000;

    for ( i = 0; i < etherpoke_conf->filter_cnt; i++ ){
        if ( pcap_session[i].fd == -1 )
            continue;

        FD_SET (pcap_session[i].fd, &fdset_read);
        last_fd = pcap_session[i].fd;
    }

    if ( last_fd == 0 ){
        syslog (LOG_ERR, "no more applicable filters left to use. Dying!");
        break;
    }

    rval = select (last_fd + 1, &fdset_read, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if ( rval == -1 ){
        if ( errno != EINTR )
            syslog (LOG_ERR, "select system call failed: %s", strerror (errno));
        break;
    }

    time (&current_time);

    for ( i = 0; i < etherpoke_conf->filter_cnt; i++ ){
        if ( FD_ISSET (pcap_session[i].fd, &fdset_read) ){
            rval = pcap_next_ex (pcap_session[i].handle, &pkt_header, &pkt_data);

            if ( rval < 0 ){
                syslog (LOG_ERR, "could not obtain packet from the queue: %s", pcap_geterr (pcap_session[i].handle));
                main_loop = 0;
                break;
            } else if ( rval == 0 ){
                continue;
            }
        }

        if ( (pcap_session[i].ts > 0)
                && (difftime (current_time, pcap_session[i].ts) >= etherpoke_conf->filter[i].session_timeout) ){
            pcap_session[i].evt_flag = FILTER_EVENT_END;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ( rval == -1 ){
        if ( errno == EINTR ) continue; else break; }` your current code falls thru; probably with unchanged fd_sets.

Comment: This does not make any sense, could you elaborate? If select fails (returns -1) program terminates (main_loop is broken). If select is interrupted by the signal, it also terminates but silently. Aside from that I can clearly see in debug output, that rval takes value >0 immediately after returning from select.

Comment: return -1 // EAGAIN is **not** an error. Just reloop or at least jump to just above the `select()` ALSO look out for differences in BSD/SYSV semantics. BSD used to restart automatically, IIRC. (BTW: EAGAIN == EINTR)

Comment: You are right that treating EINTR as an error is nonsense. I've fixed that in the codebase, thanks. But as I wrote earlier, it has nothing to do with behaviour I described in my question.

Comment: I am not going to do your dugging for you. I just pointed out the first obvious error (which is **gross**, and *very* related to the title/subject of the question) Good day. Merry Xmess!

Comment: How much is `SELECT_TIMEOUT_MS`?

Comment: `#define SELECT_TIMEOUT_MS 700`